# Entity Framework: Error: Failed to load configuration from file [...]/appsettings.json; Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity

I've come across the following error:

```
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[FourGameApp.Data.DataContext]' while attempting to activate 'FourGameApp.Data.DataContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

when attempting to run a command `dotnet ef migrations add Initial`.

The solution with changing the "Copy to output directory" setting to "Always", taken from other posts on SO dud not work, hence this question.

The code for the DataContext class:

```
using FourGameApp.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace FourGameApp.Data
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }
        public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }  
    }
}
```

Comment: you may want to include code for your data context(s).  (Looks like it's in the "Data" folder and named "DataContext.cs"?)  Also include your program.cs file.

Comment: What's your Program.cs ? Do you  register your service service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions `1[FourGameApp.Data.DataContext]' ?